# Chinese Idiom puzzle 10 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

Please solve the puzzle below

[image]

1. People use their collective wisdom and abilities to work together
2. (something good) Happens twice
3. Give no quarter
4. Awesome skill
5. Miles of waves
6. Overly militaristic; Wantonly engage in military ventures
7. Follow the leader's direction
8. 輸打贏要  Bad sportsmanship (Cantonese expression)
9. Unexpected disaster (with no fault of one's own)
10. Misfortune may turn out to be a blessing in disguise
11. Return strongly (in high profile)
12. Too happy and forgets the time to go
13. Fight and die on the battlefield
14. (Someone in a high position) Can treat talented people with respect and courtesy
15. Reward the good, punish the bad
16. Admit mistakes to the other party, ask for punishment and forgiveness
17. A heart as kind and pure as a child's
18. Have done many bad things
19. Get lost!
20. Brother harming brother
21. Palm reading: 'Career line'
22. Someone could be listening
23. Looking at things roughly without seeing the details
24. A national symbol of Canada

A. Metaphor for being loyal to each other (Similar to 肝瞻相照)

B. Leaderless

C. Conquer and unify the world

D. False things; fictional

E. Fortress

F. To try hard to save a desperate crisis; Overcome impossible odds

G. Pleasant activity

H. Will never fail; totally secure

I. The visitor is not the friendly type

J. The evil is always a step ahead ('道高一尺'下句)

K. Have done many evil deeds

L. See picture below:

[image]

M. People do not desire much would always be happy

N. Seems right on the surface, but isn't

O. Metaphor for the news spread quickly without promotion

P. 楊戩

Q. Ungrateful

R. Have no literary knowledge

S. The other name for Tofu brain (mostly in the Southen China regions)

T. Metaphor for people who used up all his tricks, and have nothing left

U. A famous quote from 項羽 after he lost his final battle, basically saying it was the heaven decided he would lose, not the fault of him fighting this war.

V. War disaster

W. heavy dust rolling

X. It is unfair and undesirable to win against an overmatched opponent.

Y. Referred to the Shanghai French concession area in the olden time.

Z. Idiom: (of trees) be luxuriant, be flourishing; (fig.) To have a lot of offsprings

Comment: What is `輸打贏要` mean ?

Comment: See https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/42082/what-is-%e8%bc%b8%e6%89%93%e8%b4%8f%e8%a6%81-cantonese-expression

Comment: seems fun but SE is more like showing some work instead of asking for all the answers. I mean you can start off with solving some of it

Comment: @wada I created this puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Formatted as a code block

(With `U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE`)

> ```
> 　　殺　　輸肝剖膽　禮　　　　隔
> 群龍無首　打　　　　賢　赤　　牆
> 策　赦　　贏　席捲天下　子虛烏有
> 群　　波　要塞　土　士　之　　耳
> 力挽狂瀾　　翁　重　　賞心樂事　
> 　　　萬無一失　來者不善　　業　
> 魔高一丈　　馬　　　　罰　　線　
> 　　　　馬　焉　　　作惡多端　　
> 梅花樁　首　知足常樂　　行　　　
> 開　　似是而非　　而　　不脛而走
> 二郎神　瞻　福　　忘恩負義　　馬
> 度　乎　　　　　　返　荊　煮　看
> 　　其　胸無點墨　　　請　豆腐花
> 黔驢技窮　妄　　非戰之罪　燃　　
> 　　　兵刀之災　　死　　　萁　　
> 　　　黷　災　　　沙塵滾滾　　楓
> 勝之不武　　十里洋場　　開枝散葉
> ```

### Down (numbers)

> 1. 群策群力 People use their collective wisdom and abilities to work together
>  2. 梅開二度 (something good) Happens twice
>  3. 殺無赦 Give no quarter
>  4. 神乎其技 Awesome skill
>  5. 波瀾萬丈 Miles of waves
>  6. 窮兵黷武 Overly militaristic; Wantonly engage in military ventures 
>  7. 馬首是瞻 Follow the leader's direction
>  8. 輸打贏要  Bad sportsmanship (Cantonese expression)
>  9. 無妄之災 Unexpected disaster (with no fault of one's own)
>  10. 塞翁失馬焉知非福 Misfortune may turn out to be a blessing in disguise
>  11. 捲土重來 Return strongly (in high profile)
>  12. 樂而忘返 Too happy and forgets the time to go
>  13. 戰死沙場 Fight and die on the battlefield
>  14. <del>敬賢下士</del> 禮賢下士 (Someone in a high position) Can treat talented people with respect and courtesy
>  15. 賞善罰惡 Reward the good, punish the bad
>  16. 負荊請罪 Admit mistakes to the other party, ask for punishment and forgiveness
>  17. 赤子之心 A heart as kind and pure as a child's
>  18. 多行不義 Have done many bad things 
>  19. 滾開 Get lost!
>  20. 煮豆燃萁 Brother harming brother
>  21. 事業線 Palm reading: 'Career line'
>  22. 隔牆有耳 Someone could be listening
>  23. 走馬看花 Looking at things roughly without seeing the details
>  24. 楓葉 A national symbol of Canada

### Across (letters)

> A. 輸肝剖膽 OR 輸肝瀝膽 Metaphor for being loyal to each other (Similar to 肝瞻相照)
>  B. 群龍無首 Leaderless
>  C. 席捲天下 Conquer and unify the world
>  D. 子虛烏有 False things; fictional
>  E. 要塞 Fortress
>  F. 力挽狂瀾 To try hard to save a desperate crisis; Overcome impossible odds
>  G. 賞心樂事 Pleasant activity
>  H. 萬無一失 Will never fail; totally secure
>  I. 來者不善 The visitor is not the friendly type
>  J. 魔高一丈 The evil is always a step ahead ('道高一尺'下句)
>  K. 作惡多端 Have done many evil deeds
>  L. 梅花樁 See picture
>  M. 知足常樂 People do not desire much would always be happy 
>  N. 似是而非 Seems right on the surface, but isn't
>  O. 不脛而走 Metaphor for the news spread quickly without promotion
>  P. 二郎神 楊戩
>  Q. 忘恩負義 Ungrateful
>  R. 胸無點墨 Have no literary knowledge
>  S. 豆腐花 The other name for Tofu brain (mostly in the Southen China regions) 
>  T. 黔驢技窮 Metaphor for people who used up all his tricks, and have nothing left
>  U. 非戰之罪 A famous quote from 項羽 after he lost his final battle, basically saying it was the heaven decided he would lose, not the fault of him fighting this war.  
>  V. <del>兵禍之慘</del> 兵刀之災 War disaster 
>  W. 沙塵滾滾 heavy dust rolling
>  X. 勝之不武 It is unfair and undesirable to win against an overmatched opponent.
>  Y. 十里洋場 Referred to the Shanghai French concession area in the olden time. 
>  Z. 開枝散葉 Idiom: (of trees) be luxuriant, be flourishing; (fig.) To have a lot of offsprings

Comment: Not too sure about V. 兵禍之慘, but nothing else seems to fit.

Comment: 14. 禮賢下士 V. 兵刀之災  ( You can edit your answer and I'll accept it)

Comment: 兵刀: https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%85%B5%E5%88%80 汉语词语，拼音为bīng dāo，意思指兵器，借指战事

Comment: @TangHo OK, edited 14 and V. Also added a code-block version. Does `U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE` achieve the correct spacing in your browser too?

Comment: Yes it does achieve the correct spacing in my browser